# Can Sharepoint search through documents not located within Sharepoint site?

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm using Sharepoint 2013.  I have documents that I don't want to store within Sharepoint.  However, I would like to include links to them within the Sharepoint site.  Is there a way to have Sharepoint search through the linked document's text when using the search feature?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In the Search Service Application where you add content sources, you can choose file shares and provide a UNC path.